# Only join if certain field is above 0

Tags: sql

This is for looking up a player, now if they're not a member of a guild it will return. So instead of several queries would it be possible to only join `ranks` and `guilds` if `p.rank_id` is greater than zero?

Would be awesome if this was possible!

```
SELECT 
  p.id, 
  p.name, 
  p.sex, 
  p.level, 
  p.city, 
  p.last_login, 
  p.comment, 
  p.skill, 
  r.name AS rank, 
  g.name AS guild 
FROM 
  players p 
INNER JOIN 
  ranks r 
ON 
  r.id = p.rank_id 
INNER JOIN 
  guilds g 
ON 
  g.id = r.guild_id 
WHERE 
  p.name = :name
```

Comment: What if `rank id = 0` what would happen? What would you do? I suspect you could do the testing in your program of choice before passing to sql.

Comment: If rank is 0 i wanna select the players table but not the joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `UNION ALL` like:

```
SELECT p.id,  p.name, p.sex, p.level, p.city, p.last_login, p.comment, p.skill, r.name AS rank, g.name AS guild 
FROM players p 
INNER JOIN ranks r 
ON r.id = p.rank_id 
INNER JOIN guilds g 
ON g.id = r.guild_id 
WHERE p.name = :name and p.rankid>0
UNION ALL
SELECT p.id,  p.name, p.sex, p.level, p.city, p.last_login, p.comment, p.skill, '' AS rank, '' AS guild 
FROM players p
WHERE p.name = :name and p.rankid=0
```

Comment: Nice to hear it works. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. Add

```
AND p.rankid > 0
```

to your `WHERE` clause, as in

```
WHERE 
  p.name = :name AND p.rankid > 0
```

Comment: But then I cant search for players that do not have a rank. You see?